# Is there any way to access a Gmail delegated account in mobile (Android, iOS, etc.)?

Tags: gmail, google-chrome, account-management, android

[Delegate and collaborate on email](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/138350) lets delegates read, send, and delete a shared account's email messages. It helpfully avoids exposing someone's general Google password to various people and risk getting the account blocked for using too many simultaneous logins.

Over Desktop one does so by:

1. Entering gmail.com
2. Clicking the little top right user icon, which opens an layover menu
3. In that menu, choosing the icon of the delegated account

The problem is step 2 does **not** exist in gmail.com's mobile version, so there's simply no icon to click (it does exist in the Gmail app, but doesn't show delegated accounts).

But if you:

1. Open the mobile browser (not the Gmail app) - tried on Google Chrome on Android on both cellular connection and Wi-Fi
2. Switch to Desktop mode in your browser's setting button
3. Go to gmail.com and log in

Or:

1. Open the mobile browser (not the Gmail app)
2. Go to gmail.com and log in
3. In the bottom of the screen choose the `Desktop` link
4. Switch to Desktop mode in your browser's setting button
5. In the bottom of the screen choose the `Standard` link

Then this icon finally shows up. Unfortunately, when you click the delegated account you just get taken into a `too many redirects` error message.

Is there any way to get pass that error message or any other way to access Gmail delegation over mobile?

[image: Open a Gmail delegated account]

Comment: Added OS, browser and type of Internet connection (although the latter seems irrelevant to me). As for troubleshooting tasks they were already there divided to steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue and solved it this way in Chrome Android:

Once the `too many redirects` error shows up, open the 3 dots menu and choose `Desktop site`.

Sadly, it seems to only work when on desktop version.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, it can be a nightmare to access a delegated account in a mobile device.

I have tried the solution using the mobile browser on desktop mode, but it only worked on an incognito tab.

The best solution I have found is to add the delegated account as any other Google account (*Android* Settings -> Google *> Add another account). To do so, it is necessary to know the delegated account password.

Using this option you can have access to the delegated account by the mobile browser and the Gmail app.

Comment: Your answer is more of a comment - may I suggest to convert it to such. It just offers to disable delegation if favor of using it as a standard account. Of course it's possible, but doesn't answer the issue (unlike the accepted answer). It means exposing someone's general Google password to various people and risk getting the account blocked for using too many simultaneous logins. I've edited the question to mention that.

Comment: The delegated account is not only used to give someone else access to one's emails but also to change the person in charge of something when someone takes on a particular role in the organization. In this sense, the function is useful from an IT perspective because it centralizes management and gives quick access to the desktop interface. Just to use it on a smartphone, it is necessary to have the password, which is often not a big deal in the case that I am focusing on. Besides, accessing an anonymous tab and making a lot of clicks is very discouraging.